# Is it better to have a time stamp through mySQL or php?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm starting to design a database and before too many records get inputted, I want to think into the future and collect as much data as possible.  I think it would be good for me to know when the record was added.  Based on your experience, is it better to do this through mySQL via datetime or through php via the date function.  I'll be using php to input all the values, so it would simply be another field.

So far, I like the php approach because I can customize it to take up minimal space: yymmddhhmm & time zone.

Based on your experience, what is the best way to store this data or are the two ways indifferent?

Also, what time zone would you suggest using?  The time zone where I am located or GMT?  Is it best to use GMT if say I were to move later on or if individuals from multiple timezones administered the database.

Answer (score 1):

Store it as `DATETIME`/`TIMESTAMP` in MySQL, it is stored as an integer anyway, just goes in and comes out as a timestamp.  Store the data in UTC.

You can manipulate the timestamp in PHP by constructing it with DateTime() and then going from there.

This also allows you to put a `NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` on the column, which saves you actively having to build it in php.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, I suggest using MySQL's timestamp field.  Because the database then understands what it is, it's stored much more efficiently than your text version (as a number, rather than a string of characters), and you can do more with it.

For example:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE foo (something TEXT NOT NULL, created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO foo (something) VALUES ("one");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO foo (something) VALUES ("two");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.13 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM foo;
+-----------+---------------------+
| something | created             |
+-----------+---------------------+
| one       | 2013-09-18 22:57:01 |
| two       | 2013-09-18 22:57:03 |
+-----------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT something, NOW() - created as seconds_since_insert FROM foo;
+-----------+----------------------+
| something | seconds_since_insert |
+-----------+----------------------+
| one       |                  136 |
| two       |                  134 |
+-----------+----------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```